# Return value from method definition that has multiple case statements

Tags: scala, playframework

```
val value = authenticateUser 

private def authenticateUser = {            
   val holder = WS.url(platformUrl + "/userApi/auth/login?username=testuser&password=testPass")
   val res = holder.post(Results.EmptyContent()).onComplete {
     case Success(response) => response.cookies.map{cookie =>   println(cookie.value.get)}
     case Failure(errors) => println("")
       // The `Future` failed.
        }
     }
```

How to return `cookie.value.get` from `authenticateUser` method?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to have *many* cookies, so it's not clear, the value of *which one* you want to return.

More importantly, you should not actually return the value itself. The idea is to return the `Future`, that can be further transformed downstream:

```
def authenticateUser = WS.url(..)
  .post(Results.EmptyContent)
  .map { _.cookies }
  .map { _.find(_.name == "Auth").flatMap(_.value).getOrElse("") }
```

Now, somewhere downstream, you can have something like:

```
 def serve(request: Request): Future[Response] = authenticateUser
    .map { user => 
        serveRequest(user, request)
    }.map { result => makeResponse(result) }
```

I don't know the specifics of Play, so, consider the `Request/Response` stuff "pseudocode", but the basic idea is that your entire processing should be a chain of `Future` transformations. The general rule is to *never* block the service thread.

Comment: Finally, I got the `Future[String]` from the chain. Now how to get `String` out of  `Future[String]` ?

Comment: As @Dima said, "your entire processing should be a chain of `Future` transformations". That means you hand the `Future` off to the framework and it will use it.

That said, if you really need to read the value NOW, for instance while debugging, this should do the trick: `scala.concurrent.Await.result(Future.successful("foo"), scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)`

Comment: @MyGod see `serveRequest(user, request)` in my snippet? The `user` there is the `String` you want. You don't need to get the `String` out of the method, that's wrong. Just get the `Future`, and then `.map` (or `.flatMap`) over it the way I showed, to process further.